# javascript: how to remove \x00 in json string

Tags: javascript

I have a json string and need to parse it it using JSON.parse()

but i need to remove all \x00 in my string

My json string:

```
'{"xd":"1","x":"285fd83"}\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

Comment: Does using replace work?

Answer (score 0):

How about using javascripts [replaceAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) method?

```js
var myString = '{"xd":"1","x":"285fd83"}\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00';

console.log(myString.replaceAll('\x00',''));
```

Comment: This is incorrect. This only replaces the first occurrence. `"\x00\x00".replace("\x00", "")` => `"\x00"`

Comment: it is not working in my console. This only replaces the first occurrence